# The identity column must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, azure

I have created a database project in Visual Studio 2012, with target platform set to 'Windows Azure SQL Database'. I added a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organization]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [CreationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate()
)

GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Organization_CreationDate] ON [dbo].[Organization] ([CreationDate])
```

But it keeps complaining about:

```
Error   1   SQL71518: The identity column '[dbo].[Organization].[Id]' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric with a scale of 0, and the column must not be nullable.  C:\Projects\Gastrology\MGP\trunk\Sources\Cfg.Mgp.Infrastructure.Database\Organization.sql   3   2   Cfg.Mgp.Infrastructure.Database
```

Anyone knows why I can't create a primary key of type guid? What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Identity columns are numeric because the database has to auto-increment them....Doing +1 against a GUID doesn't make total sense as an operation. If you want to use a GUID/UniqueIdentifier column as a PK and have the value auto-generate, then perhaps the info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx) could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDENTITY` cannot be used with `GUID`

Use [`NEWID`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) instead.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organization]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED DEFAULT NEWID(), 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [CreationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate()
)
```

Comment: This seems to have solved it. Now, if I don't want to have the database generate this Guid, but instead mu domain, can I just remove the 'DEFAULT NEWID()'?

Comment: Yes you can remove it, but you will need to insert the `Id` with the record.

Comment: Yes, my domain generates the guid. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organization]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED DEFAULT NEWID(), 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [CreationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate()
)
```

Check out this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/503fd210-b3f8-42b8-bb20-92ef475c62b6/newid-vs-identity)

From the [source](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity):-

> The main disadvantage to using GUIDs as key values is that they are
>   BIG. At 16 bytes a pop, they are one of the largest datatypes in SQL
>   Server. Indexes built on GUIDs are going to be larger and slower than
>   indexes built on IDENTITY columns, which are usually ints (4 bytes).
>   **
>   **> Not only that, but they're just plain hard to read. Unless you need a
>   truly globally unique identifier, you're probably better off sticking
>   with an IDENTITY.**

**

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have thought about this, but because my domain generates these keys and I'm developing for Azure (horizontal scaling) + distributed apps, guid is my best choice. That's why I made the id not clustered.

Answer (score 2):

The IDENTITY keyword is used to auto-increment a integer column that is usually used as a primary key. Because you are using a unique identifier, including this keyword makes no sense. (how do you increment a unique identifier?)

Just remove the "IDENTITY" keyword.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx