# How to alter column from int to Uniqueidentifier in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column "ID" as datatype int.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CLASS] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_STUDENT_DATA] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY]
)  ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now I want to change datatype from `int` to `uniqueidentifier`. I have deleted constraint `PK_STUDENT_DATA`. My `ALTER` statement is

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.STUDENT COLUMN ID uniqueidentifier
```

I am getting error:

> Identity column 'HISTORY_ID' must be of data type int, bigint,
>   smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and
>   constrained to be nonnullable.

Comment: I think you'll be better off adding a new column and renaming; because you cannot have an uniqueindentifier as identity column, your ID is also a part of your index so that should be changed as well, and if you have data in the id that's used - you'll have to deal with that as well. If the table is empty and not referenced elsewhere, then just drop it and recreate it.

Comment: It worked. I have deleted column ID and recreated it with datatype uniqueidentifier. Because identity(1,1) was not allowing to change it's datatype, as identity is a kind of constraint.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The identity column must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191846/the-identity-column-must-be-of-data-type-int-bigint-smallint-tinyint-decimal)

Comment: You **MUST** read this article [GUIDs as primary keys or clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) and see how horribly bad a `uniqueidentifier` is as the clustering key in your SQL Server table. I'd **strongly** recommend **against** doing this!

Answer (score 3):

The identity column is noncompatible with `UniqueIdentifier` data type Column.So you need to drop the column and create the new column with `UniqueIdentifier` data type.Since `IDENTITY` cannot be used with `GUID`.Use `NEWID` instead.

**Perform Following Steps:**

**1.** Initially, you need to remove the constraint from table

```
DROP Index [PK_STUDENT_DATA]  ON STUDENT
```

**2.** After that

```
ALTER TABLE STUDENT drop COLUMN ID
```

**3.** And finally

```
ALTER TABLE STUDENT 
ADD [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED DEFAULT NEWID()
```

Comment: what would be IDENTITY and UniqueIdentifier equivalent in Oracle sql pl sql ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps:

Firstly, you should remove PrimaryKey in ID column.

Secondly, you should ALTER ID column with `[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NULL` and call update command with NULL value.

Thirdly, call command `ALTER TABLE dbo.STUDENT COLUMN ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL` and set primary key to this column.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: If you want to alter colums without constraint**

First you need to drop existing column if you want to change from `INT` To `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. Do this by following way:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
DROP COLUMN COLUMN1, COLUMN2  --IF you want multiple/single column
```

After that you can add columns by following way:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD  COLUMN1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     COLUMN2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
```

**Case 2: If you want to alter colums which contains constraint**

Then firstly remove that constraint and do the above steps.

Comment: what would be UniqueIdentifier equivalent in Oracle sql pl sql ?